# Python Neural Network Library - With Dynamic Topologies

Tags: python, neural-network

I know there are questions asking for "best neural network library in Python" but I haven't found any (besides the old deprecated ones like PyBrain) which allow algorithms like NEAT and MultiNEAT and simple non-gradient/differentiation optimization algorithms like PSO to be applied. I'm working on a project involving NEAT in PyBrain but PyBrain is old and as far as I can tell very very slow.

Are there any more recent/in-progress projects in Python which allow custom neural network topologies (for example, Tensorflow and Keras seem to only allow fully-connected recurrent networks, I can't think of a way to, for example, modify those networks so they match up with a network generated by NEAT).

Comment: any more luck on this? trying to work with a NEAT defined topology myself, but having difficulty finding good frameworks to train on.